# Does formula $\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx = \frac{\int_a^b {f(x)}dx}{\int_a^b{g(x)}dx}$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is the property $$\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx = \frac{\int_a^b {f(x)}dx}{\int_a^b{g(x)}dx}$$

true for all integrable $f$ and integrable and bounded $g > 0$? Intuitively I can say it shouldn't, but I couldn't find a counterexample.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What choices of $f, g, a, b$ did you try when attempting to produce a counterexample?

Comment: Honestly, you would have to work pretty hard to come up with an *example* of a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ such that this property holds.  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @XanderHenderson $f(x)=e^{\alpha x},\, g(x)=e^{\beta x}$ for some $\alpha,\beta$ seem to be promising candidates to fulfill above equation

Comment: @tired I didn't say that the problem had no solutions (indeed $f\equiv 0$ is a solution).  I only said that you had to work hard to get functions with the given property.

Answer (score 8):

If $f(x)=g(x)$ then left side is $b-a$ and right is $1$. So...